# Adding values to a new column by aplying a formula taking into account a filter and the groups that every row belongs

Tags: r, group-by, mutate

I need to apply a formula and create a new column ('R_CO_GC_D') with these new values.

I need to filter the data frame by a column ('HOLIDAY') and group by two other columns ('SEASON' and 'TIME_SLOT') to get the mean and then subtract that mean from the original values with that specific filter for each group (the ones created by grouping two columns).

I've been trying to do so by creating a data frame with the means and then using the means inside pipes as part of a formula inside mutate but I'm getting NAs in the new column. I would like to automize this a little bit more maybe with a loop but I'm not sure the best way to achieve what I want in R.

```
Season_time_slot_media <- lr2_analysis_CO_FIL %>%
  filter(HOLIDAY == 'N') %>%
  group_by(SEASON, TIME_SLOT) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(R_CO_GC))

lr2_analysis_CO_FIL_DE <- lr2_analysis_CO_FIL %>%
  mutate(R_CO_GC_D = case_when(HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "AUTUMN" & TIME_SLOT == "07-09" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[1]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "AUTUMN" & TIME_SLOT == "10-12" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[2]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "AUTUMN" & TIME_SLOT == "13-15" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[3]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "AUTUMN" & TIME_SLOT == "16-17" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[4]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "AUTUMN" & TIME_SLOT == "18-20" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[5]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "AUTUMN" & TIME_SLOT == "21-06" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[6]) - mean(R_CO_GC)))) %>%
  mutate(R_CO_GC_D = case_when(HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SPRING" & TIME_SLOT == "07-09" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[7]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SPRING" & TIME_SLOT == "10-12" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[8]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SPRING" & TIME_SLOT == "13-15" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[9]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SPRING" & TIME_SLOT == "16-17" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[10]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SPRING" & TIME_SLOT == "18-20" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[11]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SPRING" & TIME_SLOT == "21-06" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[12]) - mean(R_CO_GC)))) %>%
  mutate(R_CO_GC_D = case_when(HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SUMMER" & TIME_SLOT == "07-09" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[13]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SUMMER" & TIME_SLOT == "10-12" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[14]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SUMMER" & TIME_SLOT == "13-15" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[15]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SUMMER" & TIME_SLOT == "16-17" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[16]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SUMMER" & TIME_SLOT == "18-20" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[17]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "SUMMER" & TIME_SLOT == "21-06" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[18]) - mean(R_CO_GC)))) %>%
  mutate(R_CO_GC_D = case_when(HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "WINTER" & TIME_SLOT == "07-09" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[19]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "WINTER" & TIME_SLOT == "10-12" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[20]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "WINTER" & TIME_SLOT == "13-15" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[21]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "WINTER" & TIME_SLOT == "16-17" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[22]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "WINTER" & TIME_SLOT == "18-20" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[23]) - mean(R_CO_GC)), 
                               HOLIDAY == 'N' & SEASON == "WINTER" & TIME_SLOT == "21-06" 
                               ~ R_CO_GC - ((Season_time_slot_media$media[24]) - mean(R_CO_GC))))
```

I hope you can help me... sorry If I didn't explain myself well... English is not my mother language.

Comment: You can use `dput(lr2_analysis_CO_FIL)` to share your data

Comment: Heidel, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a dput, using dput(head(lr2_analysis_CO_FIL)) if dput(lr2_analysis_CO_FIL) doesn't fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A merge would be helpful here...

First some example data:

```
lr2_analysis_CO_FIL <- data.frame(HOLIDAY=rep("N",96), SEASON=c(rep("AUTUMN",24),rep("SPRING",24),rep("SUMMER",24),rep("WINTER",24)), TIME_SLOT=c(rep(c("07-09","07-09","10-12","10-12","13-15","13-15","16-17","16-17","18-20","18-20","21-06","21-06"),8)), R_CO_GC=1:96)
```

Find the group means using the code from the question:

```
Season_time_slot_media <- lr2_analysis_CO_FIL %>%
  filter(HOLIDAY == 'N') %>%
  group_by(SEASON, TIME_SLOT) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(R_CO_GC))
```

Create a dataframe identical to lr2_analysis_CO_FIL but with only `HOLIDAY = "N"` entries:

```
lr2_analysis_CO_FIL.N <- lr2_analysis_CO_FIL %>%
  filter(HOLIDAY == 'N')
```

Merge the two dataframes

```
lr2.combined <- merge(lr2_analysis_CO_FIL.N, Season_time_slot_media, by=c("SEASON","TIME_SLOT"))
```

The group-specific mean is now combined with each row in lr2_analysis_CO_FIL.N:

```
> head(lr2.combined)
  SEASON TIME_SLOT HOLIDAY R_CO_GC media
1 AUTUMN     07-09       N       1   7.5
2 AUTUMN     07-09       N       2   7.5
3 AUTUMN     07-09       N      13   7.5
4 AUTUMN     07-09       N      14   7.5
5 AUTUMN     10-12       N       3   9.5
6 AUTUMN     10-12       N       4   9.5
```

Now the calculations can be done. I have replaced `mean(R_CO_GC)` with `N.mean` but if this is not right set `N.mean = 0` or something else

```
# Determine the overall mean 
N.mean <- mean(lr2_analysis_CO_FIL[which(lr2_analysis_CO_FIL$HOLIDAY == 'N'),]$R_CO_GC)

# Create the new column
lr2_analysis_CO_FIL_DE <- lr2.combined %>%
  mutate(R_CO_GC_D = R_CO_GC - (media - N.mean))
```

Done. The media column can be removed from the new dataframe if it should:

```
lr2_analysis_CO_FIL_DE <- lr2_analysis_CO_FIL_DE[,-5]
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! I really needed another perspective 